# having a fixed view across all controllers in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

For loading the views in CodeIgniter, I have to repeat loading the fixed views (header and footer) which is a little annoying to be repeated for every view-related controller.

Currently when I want to load views in CI, I do the following:

```
$this->load->view("header");
$this->load->view("index");
$this->load->view("footer");
```

Then, how can I change `$this->load->view();` to get a parameter (for instance boolean) which allows a view to be loaded before/after the targeted view. Such as this one:

```
$this->load->view("index", TRUE, FALSE, $data); // TRUE=>header  FALSE=>footer $data=>common variable
```

Is it possible to hack the function like this?

Comment: Create your template helper. Which will load all these. We have one for our internal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `library`.

Create a new library file called `template.php` and write a function called `load_template`. In that function, use above code.

> public function load_template($view_file_name,$data_array=array()) 
>   {
>
> $ci = &get_instatnce();
>
> $ci->load->view("header");
>
> $ci->load->view($view_file_name,$data_array);
>
> $ci->> load->view("footer");
>
> }

You have to load this library in autoload file in config folder. so you don't want to load in all controller.

You can this function like

> $this->template->load_template("index");

If you want to pass date to view file, then you can send via `$data_array`

Comment: wonderful, I don't know why I hadn't guessed it myself. thanks alot

Comment: @Mostafa accepting answer will help others to find the good answers

Answer (score 3):

try this library, it worked for me, when I used it

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template