# codeigniter footer hook or extending CI_Controller

Tags: codeigniter, footer

I am using Codeigniter to build my page and I ran into a small problem, I am using templates to navigate through my page. These templates contain a header, main_content and a footer. Till now it was ok but then I realised, I want to put some data into the footer that I need to load from the database. Something like the 10 most searched terms.

I was searching for an appropriate way of doing this and I came into deciding between 2 options. I can **extend my CI_Controller** into a MY_Controller in `application/core/` or I can **create a hook** that can prepare the data to be passed to every controller.

Is there any other, possibly better, option to stick to?

Comment: depends on the data your bring from the database it will be preloaded or recent 10 most searched terms if perloaded they just add the data to your template in the footer section

Comment: How are you loading the templates (header,content,footer)? If it's from library, then you can do it easily.

Comment: I need also to search for indexes in database from a list so I can create an appropriate anchor for the list item.

Comment: @kumar_v I have multiple templates that I can choose from, but every one of them contains a header, content, footer. I do it like this: `$data['main_content']="home_page"; $this->load->view('templates/default', $data);`

Comment: Refer my answer in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20608610/270037

Comment: Thats nice but I have some html in my templates too, not just header content and footer, I need to push the same data to footer at every page.

Comment: If you use library for loading template, then you can write code to fetch data from db in library itself. So you dont want to repeat the same work anywhere.

Comment: Yes thats right, so to sum up, whats the best way to do it? Library? Extending CI_Controller (kinda library) or a Hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a function within a MY_Controller that's called `_load_view`. Make sure you extend the parent controller in your your controllers. The function that I have looks something like the following... This being in `application > core > MY_Controller.php`.

```
public function _load_view($page,$data = null) {
    $data['view'] = $page; // used for a css document based on the view you're on

    $this->load->view('header/header',$data); // header contains all the meta tags/header js/css
    $this->load->view('navigation',$data); // simply just contains the navigation (only did this for ease of updating the navigation)
    $this->load->view($page,$data); // this loads your content page that would be the template that you insert all your data from your controller into
    $this->load->view('footer/footer',$data); // finally load the footer, containing js, and all that fun stuff.    
}
```

**Note:** The footer view files and header files will be placed in a header and footer directory within the views folder.

In your default controller make sure that you have something to the following extent...

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); // makes it so that there is no way that someone can access this file

class Home extends MY_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $data = array();
        $this->_load_view('view_file',$data); // references the function you created in the parent class.
    }
 }
```

In terms of the database query I'd suggest doing that in the `_load_view()` function. This ensures that the data is available on ever page and would prevent you from having to rewrite the code over and over again. The way I see it is helpers are for functions that you need access to across the board. Do the querying within a model and then load the function in the controller.

This ensures that you have the header, navigation, and footer loaded on every page, and it's consistent. Passing in the `$data` array is optional as it'll default to null if the data isn't passed through, and it will be available in all the templates. The order does matter as well. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions and I'll update my answer accordingly!

Comment: Thats a nice implementation, I have tried to use that and it works, but still I need to call my method that loads all data for the footer in every controller everywhere where I load the views. Is there something like to load all data for the views in the constructor of MY_Controller and then use the variable ? that would be awesome, I will try that :) If it wont work I will mark your answer as the correct one :) Thanks a lot for now.

Comment: Global data can be done in the _load_view(). Just think of it as any ordinary function in the controller itself as long as you're extending the MY_Controller. In the MY_Controller I'd make sure you load the CI instance. It should work as long as you pass it in as the $data variable index into the `_load_view()` method. hopefully that makes sense. It was a round about thought, lol.

Comment: OK here is what I did. I defined a global variable in MY_Controller and then filled it with some data in MY_Controller's. Now when I extend any controller with MY_Controller and write something like `$this->data` I dont have to call any other methods anywhere because everything has been done already in the constructor :)

Comment: That works as well. As long as you make the data publicly available. I would just do the work in the method because you're going to be calling that when you load the view anyways. So it would be available to the view when you load it regardless of how you do it and if you don't need to pass any data specifically from the controller then you still have the global data because of the default `$data = null` in the paramaters. So that line of including data in the controller isn't required, just used it as an example. Also the global variable has the same effect as well with my method.

Answer (score -1):

Are you aware you can call a database query in your controller and put in in $data?
For example `$data['footer'] = ....`

Then at the view you're loading in this case templates/default you echo $footer

Comment: You mean in all controllers and its functions?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to avoid :)

Comment: You could put it in a session

Comment: I didnt think of that, that is a nice idea. but I dont know if I want to put there so much data.