# Codeigniter - hand over variabel / title tag from controller to the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

i`ve a simple controller. Now i want to change the title for each site.
I want to hand over a < title > variabel like $title to my header.php ?

```
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

This is my really simple Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->home();
}

public function home() {

    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_home");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}

public function about() {
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("content_about");
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Dynamic Data to the View

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

when you want to dislay that variable data  within view 

 etc...

Comment: thank you. Now it`s working fine. I added the $data variabel to the wrong view. Now it`s working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from controller to view by passing it as a second argument to `$this->load->view()` like this:

```
$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```

[This is very clearly explained in the documentation. Please read it.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a library for handling the template work. I have already answered this kind of question in SO.

Please check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608610/270037

You can pass the title, meta_tag related items in `$data_array`.